# Manage 2-dimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am new to programming and i am trying to create a form to pass values to database through php on form submit.

In my html form i have some inputs like this:

```
<input name="lastnames[1][]" />
<input name="lastnames[2][]" />
```

etc
Now, in my php file i get lastnames array in value like this:

```
<?php
$lastname = $_POST['lastnames'];
?>
```

and i want to save the values of this array to another array and then be able to read the values of the new array.
So, i tried the following with no success:

```
//For saving values to new array:
<?php
$newarray = array();
foreach($lastname as $lastnames) {
   foreach($lastnames as $values) {
      $newarray[$lastnames][$values] = $values;
  }
}
?>
//For reading values from new array:
<?php

foreach($newarray as $lastnames) {
   foreach($lastnames as $values) {
      echo $newarray[$lastnames][$values];
  }
}
?>
```

Any ideas for this? I am trying to understand the logic through an example so can be able to work with 2-dimensional arrays, so any help really appreciated!

Comment: change  `lastnames[1][]` to `lastnames[]` abd things will become more easier

Comment: why do u need 2d array for storing multiple lastnames it can be done with 1d array.

Comment: I have one user and for each user i can add several items. Each item has an id (1,2, 3 etc). In each item someone can create another item and in new item there is the last name, so i have to know to the php side in which subitem the lastname belongs to. How else could i do this without 2-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loops through your multidimensional array and stores the results in the new array variable $newArray.

```
<?php
    $lastname=array(array("name"=>"d1","family"=>"s1"),array("name"=>"d2","family"=>"s2"));
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($lastname as $key=> $lastnames) {
        foreach($lastnames as $key2=>$values) {
            $newarray[$key][$key2] = $values;
        }
    }
    foreach($newarray as $key=>$lastnames) {
        foreach($lastnames as $key2=> $values) {
            echo $key."->".$key2."->".$values."<br>";
        }
    }
```

Also You can use reduce and use array_merge

```
$result = array_reduce($lastname, function($c,$v){
    return array_merge(array_values($c),array_values($v));
}, array());
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Another question. I want to echo for each user all his data. I do it like this: for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
 echo 'User '.$i.' : Lastname: '.$lastnamearray[$i].', Firstname: '.$firstnamearray[$i].', Marital status: '.$maritalstatusarray[$i].', Nationalities: '.$twodimensionalarrays[$i][...]).'<br>';
 }     How can inside a loop like this to echo data for each user?Assume that $twodimensionalarrays[0][$i] is for user 1, $twodimensionalarrays[1][$i] for user2 etc.